# jQuery checkboxes count total value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

What I am trying to do is to show the total from each selected checkbox for example: if I select a checkbox with the value 100 and than select another with the value 200 I get 300 as output and if I deselect it it will go off the total. I tried everything I could but no result at all, need some help in this.

This is above the html
I use PHP so I can change the values quicker

```
<?php 
    //basisprijs en titel  die erbij komen, Dit moet aangepast worden.
    $basisPrijs=
    array(
        array("titel" => 'template1', "prijs" => '100'),
        array("titel" => 'template2', "prijs" => '200'),
        array("titel" => 'template3', "prijs" => '300'),
        array("titel" => 'template4', "prijs" => '400')
    );
    //onderdelen en titel die erbij komen, Dit moet aangepast worden.
    $onderdelen=
    array(
        array("titel" => 'Table', "prijs" => '100'),
        array("titel" => 'Checkbox', "prijs" => '200'),
        array("titel" => 'List', "prijs" => '300'),
        array("titel" => 'Selectbox', "prijs" => '400')
    );
    $titel="Bereken tool";
    $check="Bestellen";
    ?>
```

And this goes after the head and Jquery

```
 <body>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript"></script> -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
      <h3><?php echo $titel; ?></h3>
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <div class="checkbox">
           <?php foreach($onderdelen as $key => $value)
           {echo "<div class='checkbox'>
           <label><input class='check' type='checkbox' value='".$onderdelen[$key]["prijs"]."' 
            name='".$onderdelen[$key]["titel"]."'>"
            .$onderdelen[$key]["titel"]."</label></div>"
                        ;}?>
          </div>
        </form>
      <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $check; ?></button>
      <p id="output">output:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
            $(".check").change(function() {
               var prijs= this.checked ? this.value : '';
               $("#output").text(prijs); 
            });
        });   
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (I didn't try it, but that's the concept):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    { 
       $('.check').change(function()
       {
           var totalPrijs=0;
           $('.check').each(function () {
               if (this.checked) {
                   totalPrijs+=parseInt($(this).val());
               }
           });

           $("#output").text(totalPrijs); 
       });

    });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen checkbox changes also on the wrapping `div` by attaching a `change` listener to it.
In the handler, set `total` to zero, and iterate through all checked inputs with class `.check`, increase `total` by value, and finally show the results.

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
    var total = 0;
    $('.check:checked').val(function (idx, val) { // Iterates checked inputs only
        total += +val;
        return val;
    });
    $('#result').text(total);
});
```

[A working demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am7664kz/2/).

Those who need multiple checkbox fields, can use this slightly modified code:

```
function countTotal () {
    var total = 0;    
    $('#' + this.id + ' .check:checked').val(function (idx, val) {
        total += +val;
        return val;
    });
    $('#res' + this.id).text(total);
}

$('.checkbox').on('change', countTotal);
```

[A working demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am7664kz/4/).

Note, that now the wrapping `div`s need an id.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".check").change(function(){
            var tot = 0;
            $(".check:checked").each(function(){
               tot += parseInt($(this).val());              
            });
            $("#output").text(tot);
        });
});
```